# Comparing Bases in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A bit of trouble with the following question:

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ consisting of the vectors $\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\cdots,\vec{v_n}$, and let $\mathcal{E}$ be some other basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Is $\big[\vec{v_1}\big]_{\mathcal{E}},\big[\vec{v_2}\big]_{\mathcal{E}},\cdots,\big[\vec{v_n}\big]_{\mathcal{E}}$ a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as well? Explain.

I'm thinking that if we can construct some matrix $S$ such that $BS = ES$, where $B$ and $E$ represent linear transformations to and from the respective bases, then the span described is in fact a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$; i.e. if $B$ and $E$ are similar, then this works. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by $[v]_{\mathcal E}$?

Comment: Consider the mapping $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $T(\alpha)=[\alpha]_\mathcal{E}$. This is the coordinate mapping with respect to the basis $\mathcal{E}$. Since $\mathcal{E}$ is a basis, it is quite straightforward to show that $T$ is an isomorphism. Hence, since $B$ is a basis, $T(B)$ is a linearly independent set of n vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$